# View node request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, httprequest, node-request

Using the Node `request` package, is there any way I can see the request body?

This is my actual request:

```
return request({
    method: 'PUT',
    preambleCRLF: true,
    postambleCRLF: true,
    url: url,
    body: stream,
    headers: {
      'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    }
  }, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('REQUEST RESULTS:', err, res.request._multipart.request, body);
  });
```

With this I am able to see the response body but not the reqest.

Comment: can u take a req parameter and console.log(req)

Comment: Doesn't give me anythign. It seems with `request` the entire request and response is in `res`. I can't see the request body within it though.

Comment: what u need actually from request body ?

Comment: I'm making a chunked request. I want to see how it appears. This is an example of what I can see in an equivalent Python progrm. I'd hope to see something similar:

stream\r\n\r\n'
send: '2'
send: '\r\n'
send: 'hi'
send: '\r\n'
send: '5'
send: '\r\n'
send: 'there'
send: '\r\n'
send: '0\r\n\r\n'

Comment: i am not pretty sure but u can fl=ollow up this documentation https://github.com/request/request
check this example `Custom HTTP Headers`
console the info 
and i dont think u r doing chunk request correctly 
accoroding to documentation it should be like `chunked: true`

Comment: I had tried setting that but saw the same results. I think chunked enabled is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible for chunked upload.